# Vaadin doesn't work with Liferay 6.2

Tags: java, liferay, vaadin, portlet, liferay-6

I try to deploy Vaadin Control Panel to Liferay 6.2 portal, but I get message "Vaadin is temporarily unavailable." on portal and error message

```
"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.PortalClassInvoker.invoke(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;"
```

As I have understood the method was removed in Liferay 6.2 version, but I can't find any available solution.

Is it possible to make it work?

Comment: Check the compatibility for Liferay 6.2 and the Vaadin version. Seems, you have to use Vaadin 7 with Liferay 6.2

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to use Vaadin 6.8.12. This is the version shipped with Liferay 6.2. You also need to follow the instructions in this [forum post](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/27917548) and add the following line to liferay-portlet.xml:

```
<portlet>
    <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
</portlet>
```

Comment: Hello sir as per instruction my portlet working fine but It do not show CKeditor field.  I am using CKeditor 1.8.2 I am using Liferay 6.2 vaadin 6.8.12 as we had migrated liferay 6.1 Vaadin  to liferay 6.2 Vaadin Thanks